# how to break up the content of a long text file to fit into multiple variables in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have a very long plain text file in my google drive which I need to parse through and select pieces of information through a script. I have successfully pulled out the text and put it into a string variable, but it is so long that the variable only contains about 1/6 of the full document.

This is the code I am using:

```js
function f09ToSpreadsheet() {
  var allFilesInFolder,cntFiles,docContent,fileNameToGet,fldr,
      thisFile,whatFldrIdToUse;//Declare all variable at once

  whatFldrIdToUse = '0B2O23fJ4nQLONlA4RlhuLWp0Y0k';
  fileNameToGet = 'Copy of RS_Tionesta_1N.txt';//Assign the name of the file to get to a variable

  //Get a reference to the folder    
  fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(whatFldrIdToUse);

  //Get all files by that name. Put return into a variable
  //allFilesInFolder = fldr.getFilesByName(fileNameToGet);
  allFilesInFolder = fldr.getFiles();
  //Logger.log('allFilesInFolder: ' + allFilesInFolder);

  if (allFilesInFolder.hasNext() === false) {
    //If no file is found, the user gave a non-existent file name
    return false;
  };

  cntFiles = 0;
  //Even if it's only one file, must iterate a while loop in order to access the file.
  //Google drive will allow multiple files of the same name.
  while (allFilesInFolder.hasNext()) {
    Logger.log("yup")
    var thisFile = allFilesInFolder.next();

    //KEY TO READING TEXT FROM .F05 & .F09 ->
    docContent = thisFile.getAs("application/octet-stream");  
    var string = docContent.getDataAsString();
    Logger.log('docContent : ' + string );
};
}
```

The "string" object, when printed to the log, only contains the first part of the text doc.

Is there *any* way to, say, split up the document into small pieces and store each part in a variable?

Comment: Perhaps calling thisFile.getBlob().getDataAsString(charset) will solve this problem.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getDataAsString()

Comment: **READ THIS:** The variable actually does contain all of the information from the text file, the reason why I believed it only contained about 1/6th is that the log truncated what was displayed to a few thousand characters. When I compared the length of the string to the length of the text document, they were the same.

This isn't an answer to my specific question, but it is a solution to this situation

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I've not tested this so apologies if it doesn't work straight away but could you get your document paragraph by paragraph and append the text like that?

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody();
var paras = body.getParagraphs();

paras.forEach(function( para ){
    var text = para.getText();
    populateSheet( text );
});
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you're thinking here. The problem is that my file is a plain text file. I can't utilize the DocumentApp library because of that unless I open each into google docs and save an additional doc file. (which isn't an option for me because I have hundreds of these files to run through so doing that manually would take a long time!)

Comment: Could you loop through your folder, create a temp google doc for each, get the text as above, and then delete the temp doc? Though that might be inefficient based on your scale. I'll have another look...

Comment: That is a reasonable solution, but the point of this script is to make the parsing of data completely automatic. I may have to result to something like that if it's not possible, though.

Comment: Oh, I meant to write a script that does that for you - I wasn't suggesting doing that yourself! ;) automation ftw...

Comment: I found the solution! The variable does contain all of the data, the log simply truncates what it displays to a few thousand characters. One of my engineer friends figured that out. Don't worry about writing that script, it's not necessary anymore.

Comment: I hope you didn't waste too much time on that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: no problem at all, I learned something from it too. The joys of SO :)